# my slide menu button and Tabbar items not working/populating in reveal viewcontroller . why?

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I have used revealviewcontroller in which  I take a view controller and set its sw_front to a tabbar controller and sw_rear to tableview controller. when I am running , its working fine  . In tabbar controller I have added 5 different view controllers and same items in tableview cells also dynamically in sw_rear part. In table view for each cell i have connected the dynamic cells to its related view controller based on its indexpath.row  . But when i click on it the  tabbar items is not coming . the navigation items are coming because before every view controller i have embed the navigation controller. why the tabbar items are not coming???

For better understanding I am sending few codes and screens

**codes**

I have set the tableview like this for each dynamic cell

```
switch(indexPath.row)
    {
    case 0 :
        print("1st row")
       //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueIdentifier", sender: self)
        let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
        let vc : UINavigationController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("homeVC") as! UINavigationController
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

        case 1 :
        print("2nd row")
        let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
        let vc : UINavigationController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("menuVC") as! UINavigationController
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But when i click on ,it goes to view controller but tabbar items not coming

**screens**

[image]

This screen is the first view .Here you can see the tabor items are coming .Now clicking on slide menu the screen is

[image]

the dynamic data is coming . now clicking on for example home the screen shows like this
[image]

here no tabbar items are there and the sliding menu button is not working .
where i am doing mistake??

Below is the code for setting reveal view controller on slide menu button:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    if self.revealViewController() != nil{
        slideBtn.target = self.revealViewController()
        slideBtn.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should go back to using `performSegueWithIdentifier` instead of `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`, since you have custom segues. Use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method for choosing segue. Read [this](http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/) tutorial for setting up segues and nav/tabbar controllers properly

Comment: that way also i have  tried .you  can see that in coding i have make it a comment  ,bcoz its not working

Comment: And how can i create segue  with dynamic cells. if the cell is static its possible to create segue but in dynamic i have no idea

Comment: @PRADIPKUMAR answer corrected. Your question is too wide, so main answer idea still read more documentation

Comment: I can understand . the link you have sent I saw. Actually my table viewdata is not static that i can create segue for each view controller . here the number of tableview cells and its data are  dynamically coming

Comment: @PRADIPKUMAR as I see on screenshot - you can add segue for every possible case. Or you can make one segue to empty controller and then customize it as you wish in prepareForSegue.